# Car sputters and tries to die when taking off in first gear

Tags: chevrolet, stall

I have a 5-speed manual transmission 1990 Chevy beretta gtz. Up until recently the car has run fine with no problems. A few days ago I noticed when I was about to go for a drive the car started to sputter and sounded like it was about to die as I was trying to leave the parking spot. I immediately put the car in neutral and could clearly hear the engine sounded different than normal like it was halfway running (engine/exhaust sounded half as loud). While sitting there I Rev the engine a little and after the rpms dropped the car sounded normal again. Over the past few days every time I start moving from a complete stop the car sputters and tries to stall unless I really raise the rpms (6-7k) while releasing the clutch. I also noticed the car was putting out A LOT of exhaust that smells like gas (running rich?) any ideas of what may be my problem? Also my check engine light is not on and hasn’t come on.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Finally had a chance to take a look under the hood. I heard what sounded like a vacuum leak. After listening around for it I found the source which was one of the tubes going to my fuel regulator was barely on and pulling fuel.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it figured out ... you should write it as an answer!